# Multiple tables with foreign key or single table with foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

This demonstrates my lack of knowledge of database design principles. I'm trying to create a database and I have about 150 tables, each containing a different type of "resource". Each type of resource can have an identifier, which is made up of a value which is a string, and a url specifying the system that defines the value.

Example:

```
"system": "urn:oid:0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7"
"value": "654321"
```

All identifiers, regardless of the type of resource, are of this format, and a single resource can have multiple identifiers.

So is it better to have a single table that specifies the `resourceType` and an ID and ll identifiers are in the same table, or should I have a different table of identifiers for each resource?

For instance, if I have 3 `resourceTypes`, `Patient`, `Practitioner` and `Organization`, each having roughly this format:

```sql
create table if not exists patient 
(
    id text primary key,
    versionid int not null,
    updatedat timestamp with time zone default timezone('utc'::text, now()) not null,
    resource jsonb not null,
);
```

Then I would have an identifier table for each resource table:

```sql
create table if not exists patientIdentifier 
(
    id text primary key,
    resourceId text not null,
    value text not null,
    system text not null,
);
```

OR, I could have a single identifier table for all resource tables:

```sql
create table if not exists patientIdentifier 
(
    id text primary key,
    resourceType text not null,
    resourceId text not null,
    value text not null,
    system text not null,
);
```

Is there one structure that is generally preferred over another?

Comment: I find it hard to imagine your database. It sounds like you just want to have an inventory of ressources. Each ressource belongs to a ressource type and you want to be able to list ressources with their ressource type data. This would be two tables, one for the types, one for the ressources. A very simple database with only this one relation and just for the purpose to store and list these entities. Actually, you wouldn't even need a relational database for this. A mere XML or JSON file might suffice.

Comment: If, on the other hand you want to deal with patients treated by practitioners belonging to some organizations, etc., then you'd build a database of these entities. A patients table, a practioners table, an organization table, a table representing patient_of_practioner, etc. This would be a very typical relational database of 1:n and m:n relations. But why then the idea of abstract ressorces and ressource types? And this wouldn't match your description that a patient is merely a url and a value either. So this may not be what you are after.